# Intel 865G chipset drivers

Tags: 10.10, drivers, intel-graphics

Is it important to install chipset drivers on Ubuntu? I'm not using onboard graphics but in windows it is important I think, I got linux drivers for my chipset and never tried to install them (Hard way no .deb files, only manual installation) i'm not talking about installing VGA drivers but Lan and other motherboard drivers,except Audio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chipset support and other drivers are part of the Linux kernel - you do not need to install a separate driver package for the majority of hardware. Intel hardware in particular is well supported. If your hardware works, you already have the best available support for your distribution (short of messing about with custom kernels).

Answer (score 1):

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

do that in your terminal and it will show you what kind of drivers needed .

for more information on drivers you can use this link as a reference . 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

Comment: It only shows my Graphics card, What else should it show?

Comment: actually my system also Intel . i havent installed Graphics drivers . my system works fine . if you wanna know whats your system video memory then do as sudo lshw -C video in your terminal , then it will show you how much memory allocated for video .